# Major differneces or updates in Azure Devops Server 2019 compared to TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-server-2019

We currently are running 2018.3 version of TFS instance in our environment and were looking to upgrade to the recent version of Azure DevOps Server 2019. I looked up online at various places to find out the  differences between these two version and was unable to find one. Hence wanted to check with the community here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you should find that`s new in the AzDo 2019. There are many additional features were added into 2019 version. Here is the index of new features: [Azure DevOps Server 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/whats-new?view=azure-devops#azure-devops-server-2019). If you have interest in some specific areas, you can point them to discuss. For me:

1. [Azure SQL Database support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019#support-for-azure-sql-database)
2. [New web portal navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019#new-navigation-experience)
3. [Publish from a Git repository](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019#publish-markdown-files-from-a-git-repository-as-a-wiki)
4. [Attach files and images in folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019#attach-files-and-images-in-folders)
5. [Query work with +/- @CurrentIteration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019#query-work-across-the-iteration-schedule-with---)
6. [Query work for a team with the @TeamAreas macro](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/release-notes/azuredevops2019#query-work-in-the-area-paths-of-a-team-with-the-new--macro)
7. Deprecated integration with MS Project

Comment: Thank you @Shamrai for the response, I was actually intending to find the differences between 2017 vs 2019, would that be something you would be able to guide me with.